# Industry average for security as a percentage of product budget?

Tags: web-application, defense, budget, embedded-system

Lets assume the product is pure software or a blend of software and cheap commodity hardware.

Is there any work showing what the average industry spending is on just the security aspects as a percentage of the total product development costs?

I do see [this post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4118/secure-development-costs) but that only talks about estimating absolute $ figures from bottom-up. I'm looking for a relative or % of the total budget figure for a top-down assessment. I understand the range might not be as tight as we'd like

EDIT: We are the developers (SMB, veteran owned), presenting to the customer(s) (US Govt entities) to protect critical infrastructure. Product can be thought of a system running custom software on commodity embedded hardware. There will also be a web-application for the same customer for a similar focus (protect/monitor critical infra), but that's being tracked as a separate product/budget. So also interested in that.

EDIT#2: One can totally argue that the context means the costs are "inherent" or 100%. We got some push back saying "*Can be built by gluing A, B and C at $XYZ. That is insecure, we know but why the extra 60% just to make it more secure?*"

Comment: The range is from 0-100%, depending on industry being sold to and the nature of the product. You are going to need a lot more detail if you want a more detailed response.

Comment: @schroeder: Sorry, added more context.

Comment: You have to conduct a **detailed**, bottom-up threat & risk (CYA) analysis of all relevant alternatives. A horde of Eastern Asian hackers eagerly awaits the results. Top-down stuff doesn't translate well between projects.